# Why NullPointerException when programmatically add my text view?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget, android-manifest

I programmatically created a linear layout in my Activity like the following:

```
LinearLayout myContent = new LinearLayout(this);
myContent.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
```

Then, I defined a text view in xml (under res/layout/) like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/name_text"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:gravity="center"
/>
```

After that, I would like to add several `TextView` defined above to `myContent` linear layout programmatically like below:

```
//my content is a linear layout
LinearLayout myContent = new LinearLayout(this);
myContent.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
  //get my text view resource
  TextView nameField = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.name_text);


  nameField.setText("name: "+Integer.toString(i)); //NullPointerException here
}

myContent.addView();
```

I thought the above code should add 10 `TextView` with name into `myContent` linear layout. But I end up with a **NullPointerException** at `nameField.setText(...);` (see above code) Why?

### P.S. (Update)

`myContent` Linear Layout is added to another linear layout which is defined in main.xml, and my activity **has** setContentView(R.layout.main)

Comment: Where is your setContentView(R.layout.youtrlayoutid), before you attach your layout ?

Comment: @ sat , check my update, I did setContentView(R.id.main), all the above layout code is only part of my main.xml, I use the above code to implement a dynamic layout feature

Comment: You should use an Inflater to use those text fields!

Comment: if Your R.id.name_text is in another layout, you have to inflate that layout and then attach it, bec when you call reference to R.id.name_text, it cannot be found because your layout is not present unless its inflated.

Comment: @sat, you are right! After I inflate the layout then things are getting right. Could you please move your comment to an answer so that I can accept your answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your R.id.name_text is in another layout, you have to inflate that layout and then attach it,
because when you refer to R.id.name_text, it cannot be found because your layout is not present unless its inflated.

e.g.

View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.child);
myContent.addView(child);

Answer (score 2):

Problem is in this line

```
 TextView nameField = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.name_text);
```

.See there is a mismatch with the spelling in the layout file.and also assure `setContentView(R.layout.main);`I ran your code.It runs fine.

Comment: @ Rasel , where is the mismatch with spelling of R.id.name_text ??? I don't see. About R.id.main that was my typo only.

Comment: if you set your layout like setContentView(R.layout.main); where main is your layout file and is there any TextView named name_text there, then your code is okay.So i told you to see that

Comment: what is R.id.main.Didn't you use setContentView

Comment: @ Rasel, yes, I am using R.layout.main, please forget about this. Just some misunderstanding. How do you think about @sat 's comment, he mentioned to inflate layout first because my TextView(id=name_text) is a layout file .  Though you don't have problem when you are running the code, I have same problem still, so I think may be his words worth to consider.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't called setContentView(...) with a layout file. It sounds like what you may want to do is create the 10 views in code and apply some styling to them instead.

You can't access these 10 view with findViewById(...) as your layout file only specifies one view. You could also import that layout 10 times into a main layout file with the LinearLayout  defined as the parent view.

Comment: @ ScouseChris , check my update, I did setContentView(R.id.main), all the above layout code is only part of my main.xml, I use the above code to implement a dynamic layout feature

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [Link](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/130521-android-part-iii-dynamic-layouts/) the checkbox . What you're doing is create a layout dynamically and with an xml, just choose one.